# I Need to Update a Value in Mongodb Shell Using Operations

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have one field that I need to update called "Costo"
My query in the shell is:

```
db.proyectos.update(
{"Días de Desviación":{$gte:5}},
{ $set:{"Costo":{$inc:{ $mul: [ "$Costo", .05 ] } } } },
{ multi: true } )
```

I have to increment 5% the Cost of all entries (registers) in the collection where Días de Desviación is greater than 5

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer if you review the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question.

Comment: To do multiple arithmetic operations on the same field you have to use [Aggregation arthmetic operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/index.html#arithmetic-expression-operators). See this post: [Coming in MongoDB 4.2: Pipeline Powered Updates and More Expressive Queries](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/coming-in-mongodb-42-pipeline-powered-updates-and-more-expressive-queries).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need both `$set` and `$mul`, and since `Cost + (Cost * 0.05) == Cost * 1.05`, you can do without the $inc as well, and just run

```
db.proyectos.update(
                    {"Días de Desviación":{$gte:5}},
                    { $mul: { "Costo": 1.05 } },
                    { multi: true } 
                   )
```